# Is there a more efficient way of coding this?

Tags: php, performance, naming-conventions, theory

The code in question is the code contained within the 2nd foreach loop, the purpose of which is to prevent exact duplicate latitude and longitudes.

```
foreach($aUsers as $k => $v)
{
    // generate address
    $aAddress = array();
    if(!empty($v['city_location']))
        $aAddress[] = $v['city_location'];
    if(!empty($v['country_child_id']))
    {
        $aRow = $oDb->select('name')
             ->from(getT('country_child'))
             ->where('child_id = \''.$v['country_child_id'].'\'')
             ->execute('getRow');
        $aAddress[] = $aRow['name'];
    }
    if(!empty($v['postal_code']))
        $aAddress[] = $v['postal_code'];
    if(!empty($v['country_iso']))
    {
        $aRow = $oDb->select('name')
             ->from(getT('country'))
             ->where('country_iso = \''.$v['country_iso'].'\'')
             ->execute('getRow');
        $aAddress[] = $aRow['name'];
    }
    $sAddress = implode(', ',$aAddress);
    /// get location
    $aLatLon = $oGeoMap->getLatLon($v['user_id'],1,$sAddress);
    if($aLatLon['success'] === true)
    {
        foreach($aUsers as $k2 => $v2)
        {
            $iAdd = .01;
            $iAttempts = 0;
            while($v2['latitude'] == $aLatLon['latitude'] && $v2['longitude'] == $aLatLon['longitude'])
            {
                $iAttempts++;
                switch($iAttempts){
                    case 1:
                        $aLatLon['latitude'] += $iAdd;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $aLatLon['longitude'] += $iAdd;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $aLatLon['latitude'] += $iAdd;
                        $aLatLon['longitude'] += $iAdd;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $aLatLon['latitude'] -= $iAdd;
                        $aLatLon['longitude'] -= $iAdd;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $aLatLon['latitude'] += $iAdd;
                        $aLatLon['longitude'] -= $iAdd;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $aLatLon['latitude'] -= $iAdd;
                        $aLatLon['longitude'] += $iAdd;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        $iAdd += .01;
                        $iAttempts = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        $aUsers[$k]['latitude'] = $aLatLon['latitude'];
        $aUsers[$k]['longitude'] = $aLatLon['longitude'];
        $aUsers[$k]['address'] = $sAddress;
    }
    else
        unset($aUsers[$k]);
}
```

Comment: Are you having problems with performance? You know the old saying: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" ...

Comment: We are all zen mind readers...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is $attempts is synonim for $iAttempts? why aren't you using $k2 and $v2?

Comment: @jan: No, I coded this and it looks ugly. I'm hoping there's a php array guru here that can help make this more efficient, namely getting rid of the 2nd loop that hopefully is unnecessary.

Comment: I'd guess that the best optimization would be to allow duplicate latitudes and longitudes.  Randomly fudging the data until you achieve uniqueness seems sloppy.

Comment: You are really not clear on what your code is doing, elaborate some more ...

Comment: Jan, this "old saying" is a common substitute for /dev/brain. Writing code in optimal way has nothing to do with premature optimization. And *this* seems to be in sheer need of rewrite. But I'd first migrate it into plain English.

Comment: Perhaps you should concentrate on optimizing for readability first, as that seems to be the more pressing issue for your code.

Comment: @jan - added the latlon lines up top for clarification. There's actually more code to this but i omitted the unnecessary parts.

@frank, thanks i fixed that

@michael - sorry, code convention, can't change it

@mark - howso? if you're referring to formatting, it looks rather nice from gedit but the spacing is all jacked when i copy and paste

Comment: Add some comments and include the full code, nobody is going to optimize something if they don't understand exactly what you're up to. Some of the variables you are using in your loops haven't even been set yet, it'd be nice to know their initial values or scope of the variables.

Comment: Citizen, first, never stick to code convention just for the sake of it, second, I meant using verbal description instead of code.

Comment: Ok, switched the main post to display full code.

Comment: I agree... you're going to have much more luck here if you can summarize the purpose of the code.  This will help someone see a better way to do what the real purpose of the code is.  As it stands, you're saying: make it do exactly this, but different.

Comment: @michael: the cc is not for the sake of it. If it helps, prefixes are a = array, i = integer, b = boolean, r = resource, s = string

Comment: @danieltalsky: the purpose of the script is to gather user addresses from the db, get the latitude and logitude, but prevent exact duplicates. If anyone needs more explanation than that, they probably cannot help me anyway.

Comment: Citizen, it doesn't. It's just that you belie it does ;-)

Comment: @Citizen: I think you are trying to do too much in one function. For example, the logic for choosing new points could be moved out into a separate class/function. As could the test to see if a point is unique. In fact as the code is written now it even seems that there is a bug because your uniquifying fudging could move a point to land on another point that you've already checked once, and then you would miss it because you don't seem to go back and check it again.

Comment: Mark, that's the first thing I noticed. Another reason not to call redoing this code "premature optimization".

Comment: @Citizen: what difficulties do duplicate positions pose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly agree with Frank Farmer's comment, but if you insist on this way of doing things try something along these lines:

```
$lls = array();
static $offs = array( array(1,0), array(0,1), array(1,1),
    array(-1,-1), array(1,-1), array(-1,1) );

foreach($aUsers as $k=>&$v) {
    $lla=$la=somelat; $llo=$lo=somelong;
    for($add=.01;isset($lls["{$lla}x$llo"]);$add+=.01) {
        foreach($offs as $o) {
            $lla=$la+$o[0]*$add; $llo=$lo+$o[1]*$add;
            if(!isset($lls["{$lla}x$llo"])) break;
        }
    }
    $lls["{$lla}x$llo"] = true;
    $v['latitiude']=$lla; $v['longtitude']=$llo;
    $v['address'] = $sAddress;
}
```

That is, if I understand your intention correctly. And change variable names to adhere to your standards yourself ;-)

Code is untested.

And no, I'm not going to re-read the full code ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Frank's suggestion doesnt apply becuase this is for display purposes only, on a map. Duplicates simply won't show, so I have to prevent them.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a second data structure that holds existing latitude+longitude positions, e.g. a 2-D array of users indexed by latitude then longitude. Rather than looping over the `$aUsers` array, you check whether a given latitude and longitude exists within this other data structure.

Note that as you can only use integers and strings as array keys and casting floating point numbers to either integers or strings will result in a loss of precision, you should convert floating point numbers to their bit-string equivalents if you're using latitude and longitude as keys. A simple `pack('d', $l)` should work, or you could use:

```
function fl2hex($l, $fmt='d') {
    $hex = unpack('H*', pack($fmt, $l));
    return $hex[1];
}
```

If you know your latitude and longitude are stored as floats and not doubles (though I'm fairly certain PHP only uses doubles), you can use 'f' as the pack format rather than 'd'.

For readability, you can refactor parts of the code (e.g. the `switch($iAttempts)`) as additional functions.

As for the problem of multiple people at a single location, another solution (assuming the map is displayed on a screen, rather than printed) is to use a different indicator for a group of people. When a user mouses over the group icon, it can "explode" into a star of individual icons (if that makes sense), each with a line connecting the icon to the people's location. I've seen something similar in a couple applications, but can't think which ones right now.

Comment: You don't really need a 2D array here.

Comment: outis, what loss of precision?! Over 0.01 when computing lattitude and longtitude? And what precision does he need to avoid collisions?

Comment: @Michael: when Citizen is testing whether someone exists at a given location, he isn't doing it within a tolerance, though perhaps he should. My recommendation is intended to match the behavior of his existing code.

Comment: Ah, you haven't read his comment to my answer. I think he would actually prefer to lose some precision. And, perhaps, more than converting to string will provide him with ;-)

Comment: @Michael: I read it, but (without seeing the live version) didn't wish to assume what would work best. Instead, I went for compatibility. Are you thinking a `sprintf('%0.2f', $l + 0.005)` or a `round` is in order?

Comment: I think you're taking it too far ;-) I would go for %.3f precision considering .01 increment.  But then it depends. Don't ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use switch() with a semicolon... E.g.

```
switch($attempts) {
    case 1;
    case 3;
    case 5;
        $aLatLon['latitude'] += $iAdd;
    break;
}
```

Haven't tested this; but I'm sure if you keep going like this or something similar, it will work.

Hopefully that helped

Comment: How is semicolon different from colon? Except for it looks hideous?

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion:

This is more of a general suggestion for all the code, not just the inner loop. I would change the code to use dedicated structures instead of arrays. Here's a basic example:

```
foreach($aUsers as $k => $v)
{
    $userInfo = new UserInfo($v);

    // generate address
    $sAddress = $userInfo->getAddress();

    /// get location
    $latLonResult = $oGeoMap->getLatLon($userInfo->user_id, 1, $sAddress);
    ...
}
```

## Actual answer:

As far as optimizing the inner loop, I would just **delete that code**. Either come up with a new UI element for having multiple users in the same location, or ignore a user if their lat/long has already been added to the map.

If you must keep it, Michael's solution looked good.

Comment: Actually, except for minor syntactical differences your suggestion and my solution aren't mutually exclusive. I'm not sure whether your proposal is an improvement. But it won't do any harm either.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was implied.